# Reordering items in a GridView with a VariableSizedWrapGrid in WinRT

Tags: windows-runtime, winrt-xaml, windows-store-apps

I want to create VariableSizedWrapGrid like [this](http://leeontech.wordpress.com/2012/03/01/customizing-gridview-items-in-metro-app-4/)

BUT, I also want the items to be draggable (the CanReorderItems property), according to [this](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-GB/winappswithcsharp/thread/70626f1d-303b-4605-aeff-fe80337a3769) post this is not supported because the lack of 'some' interfaces..
I tried it and indeed the reordering stops working if I use the VariableSizedWrapGrid.

Could anybody point me in the right direction of the interfaces that are missing to get this done?

Comment: we posted the sample implementation here: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/536519/Extending-GridView-with-Drag-and-Drop-for-Grouping

Comment: That is a GREAT example.. exactly what I was looking for. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Flores,

You pretty much have to implement the drag events yourself.

Here's an excellent blog post detailing what you need to do:

http://www.renauddumont.be/en/2012/windows-8-csharp-xaml-drag-drop

However, the blog doesn't mention how to do the DragOver logic very well.  Basically, you have to check what item you're over, and then depending on the direction (dragging up/down/left/right) you have to call the corresponding visual state to get the smooth animation.

So for example, if the dragged item was over an item below it (you can check based on the item's index in your collection), then you need to do something like:

```
VisualStateManager.GoToState((Control)containerOfItemBelow, "BottomReorderHint", true);
```

BTW, if you're using a GroupedDataSource, Drag & Drop would also be broken.  I found that I can skirt the whole GroupedDataSource concept easily by nesting Gridviews & Listsviews.

HTH

Comment: Do you maybe have a good example of this? I can't get it to work and can't find any good example on the internet..

Comment: Didn't the above example help you? it implements the Drag & Drop events needed to make this work.

Comment: Yes, but as you mentioned the dragover is the problem.. how do I get to the containerOfItemBelow exactly? Not with the items[] property.. I can't find a property on the grid that holds the controls of the items.

Comment: If you have the item (data item), then you can get the container using this syntax: var control = itemGridView.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem(dataItem);