# Wrtiing WinRT GridView Drag and Drop Handler

Tags: gridview, windows-runtime

In WinRT, I am trying to implement a custom drag and drop handler for my variable sized GridView. In the DragItemsStarting handler, I can get the item being dragged by using e.Items.FirstOrDefault().

I only have one GridView, so the item will be dropped somewhere inside of it. If it is dropped on another item, I need to know what that item is so that I can insert the item being dragged into that position.

How can I get that item? [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13950192/reordering-items-in-a-gridview-with-a-variablesizedwrapgrid-in-winrt) thread mentions using GridView.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem(item) but this does not seem to work and I can't find any good examples of a Drop event.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can handle OnDragOver and OnDrop events, take pointer position from event arguments, then get all elements under the pointer using VisualTreeHelper.FindElementsInHostCoordinates, then analyze these elements and find the correct one, and only then you can get an item with ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem. 
But you will need even more as end-user can drop to some place, where there is no any items.
You can take a look at out sample which does it here: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/536519/Extending-GridView-with-Drag-and-Drop-for-Grouping